# Python tkinter: Tab page with scroll bar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a tab page with a text box on it and I want to add a scroll bar to it, but it isn't working for me (it is covering the tab name).

Here is my code:

```
*Look below*
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

I am probably being stupid, but now when I switch between tabs the text doesn't change (if I type 'a' and switch between tabs it show up on all of them), and that didn't happen before until I edited the code. Here is my code; let me know if you need more of it:

```
tabs = {}
tab_bar = {}

...
def doNew(self):
  # Create a new tab with the file name and select it
  self.nb.select(self.CreateTab())

# Create a new tab
def CreateTab(self, name='Untitled.asm'):

  tab_num = len(tabs)   # get current tab number
  tab_bar_num = len(tab_bar)  # get it's frame as well

  tab_bar[tab_bar_num] = Frame(self.nb)   # create a new frame

  scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.root)
  scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

  tabs[tab_num] = Text(self.root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
  self.nb.add(tab_bar[tab_bar_num], text=name)   # add tab


  tabs[tab_num].pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
  scrollbar.config(command=tabs[tab_num].yview)

  return tab_num
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab should be a frame that is a child of the notebook. Then, the text widget and scrollbar should be in the frame.

Comment: @user2638731: you didn't do what I suggest: the text widget and scrollbar need to be a child of the frame, not a child of self.root.